# Open image in same page as lightbox in php

Tags: php, jquery, lightbox

I have created a form in which there is a png image as a watermark and a main image. I have to open this in **light-box**. My code for this is shown below:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// Load the watermark and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('store/left.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('store/Lighthouse.jpg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 500;
$marge_bottom = 500;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
}
```

and the preview of this code is:

[image]

I want to do this while I'm in a light-box. How can I do this?

Comment: just google for light-box and take your favorite one

Comment: @donald123 I have try light-box in html but How can i use with the php script?

Comment: Your PHP is parsed into HTML which is rendered by your browser. As such, you cannot open a LightBox using PHP. Could you maybe post the HTML of your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="engine/css/vlightbox1.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="engine/css/visuallightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="engine/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="engine/js/visuallightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="engine/js/vlbdata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
<div align="center">
<!-- Start VisualLightBox.com BODY section id=1 -->
<div id="vlightbox1">
...
</div>
<!-- End VisualLightBox.com BODY section -->
</div>
...
</body>
```